# Demonstrate that the limit does not exist.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Is the following reasoning sound for demonstrating that the limit does not exist. The limit is:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{x^y}$$

I show that the restriction gives me two different values of the limit as follows:
$$\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)}{x^y}=\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)}0^y=0$$
$$\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)}{x^y}=\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)}x^0=1$$

Therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: Well done ! You have shown that the limit does not exist by showing two ways of $(x,y)$ approaching to $(0,0)$ giving different limits.

Comment: @Peter Thanks :)

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful. $0^y$ is not defined for negative values of $y$.

Comment: @MathPanda So it is not a valid argument for saying the limit doesn't exist. Can you give me any direction? I don't understand how I'd proceed.

Comment: @MathPanda Would my argument still hold if I calculate the value of the limit for positive values of the y? like so:
$$\lim_{y^+ \to 0}0^y=0$$

Comment: @Harry yes, the argument still holds. The correct notation is $y\rightarrow 0^+$. Are you able to convince yourself using $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of limit that your argument works?

Comment: @MathPanda Pardon for the bad annotation. I am new to latex.
Following the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition both right and left-handed limits need to exist. In this case, we only have the right-hand limit in $(0,0)$. Therefore the limit doesn't exist for the restriction $x=0$. So the starting limit doesn't exist. 
If this is what you were meaning, I am asking myself if there was the need to calculate the limit on the restriction $y=0$, which as I showed above is 1.
I think that step is not necessary as on the restriction $x=0$ we cannot find the limit therefore it is not defined.

Comment: @Harry the domain of the function $x^y$ is not entirety of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So at $x=0$, you cannot talk about both sided limit. The point I am trying to make is that similar to the proof of uniqueness of limit, you can prove that the limit at $(0,0)$ doesn't exist. I could write an answer explaining the details if you want. Let me know about it.

Comment: @MathPanda Yes. I would love to have a concise answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to choose a proper domain as the function $f(x, y) = x^y$ cannot be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. One of the most straightforward fixes is to take the domain to be $[0, \infty)\times [0, \infty)\setminus \{(0, 0)\}$.

Now suppose that $\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}f(x, y)$ exists and is equal to $l$. This implies that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x, y)-l|<1/4$ whenever $||(x, y)||<\delta$. Choose $y$ such that $\delta>y>0$. For such a $y$, $|f(0, y)-l| = |l|<1/4$. Now choose $x$ such that $\delta >x>0$. For such an $x$, $|f(x, 0)-l| = |1-l|<1/4$. This gives us $|l|+|1-l|<1/2$, which using triangle inequality implies that $1<1/2$, a contradiction.